# Delete row with certain string found in one of the columns

Tags: python, pandas

New to pandas and python, and I thought my code was correct however it isn't doing my intended action. I have a dataset which I want to clean, and within it, I want to remove rows that contain the word 'No Location'. I thought it was correct however when trying it, it hasn't been successful. My code is the following:

```
df = df[df.Location != 'No Location']
```

The column is called `Location`, the string I want to use is `No Location`. Again, I just don't understand why these rows are not being deleted unless I missed something out? Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: I suggest you print the value of `df` before and after you use the code above. It will help see what your line of code does.

Comment: The string 'No Location' might have some whitespaces. Try df.Location = df.Location.str.strip() and then your code again.

Answer (score 0):

If you have words 'No Location' as substring, you may try:

```
df = df[~df.Location.str.contains('No Location')]
```